# What is Default Dispatcher Kotlin flow function?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have one question about multithreading and coroutine flows. I have one flow function that emits flow in the usecase and repository call to the network with suspend functions. But I don't use withContext(Dispatchers.IO) to change Dispatcher because some tutorial videos don't use it. I write the current thread name to loggat and I saw all works "Main thread". What I don't know about flows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> repository call to the network with suspend functions

These suspend functions should be responsible for delegating to an appropriate dispatcher internally, if they need to. But if you're using a library that properly incorporates suspension, you don't need to worry about this. For example, suspend functions defined as Retrofit request functions will automatically handle proper suspension under the hood.

So, if you're using proper suspend functions, you don't need to specify a dispatcher when calling them.

Pretty much the only place you should ever see `flowOn` is immediately following either a `flow { }` builder call, or some kind of transforming operator like `map` that does heavy *blocking* work. If we're following good encapsulation practices and coroutines convention, we would not expose a Flow in a public property or function that requires the caller to assign the dispatcher. For instance:

```
val goodFlow: Flow<Int> = flow {
    repeat(100) {
        Thread.sleep(1000L) // simulate heavy calculation/file reading, etc.
        emit(Random.nextInt())
    }
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

/**
 *  A Flow that does heavy blocking work. Make sure you flow on Dispatchers.IO 
 *  if you collect this or you will block your main thread. Don't forget!!!!!
 */
val badFlow: Flow<Int> = flow {
    repeat(100) {
        Thread.sleep(1000L) // simulate heavy calculation/file reading, etc.
        emit(Random.nextInt())
    }
}
```

The `badFlow` above relies on the caller to remember to do something to avoid breaking the functionality, and has to remind the programmer in the documentation and hope they see it and don't forget. This fragility and convolution can be avoided by practicing good encapsulation.

Suspend functions are handled the same way--they should never block and therefore require the caller to call them on a specific dispatcher.

If you are using libraries like Retrofit, OkHttp, Firebase, Android Jetpack (Room, DataStore), Google Play Billing, etc., these all follow proper convention. You never have to use `withContext` to call their suspend functions and you never have to use `flowOn` on Flows that they return.

So if your use case function is like this, it's fine. You don't need `flowOn`.

```
fun retrieveFooMonitor(argument: Foo, interval: Long): Flow<Bar> = flow {
    while (true) {
        emit(someRetrofitService.getFoo(argument)) // calling a suspend fun
        delay(interval)
    }
}.retry { e-> (e is IOException).also { if (it) delay(interval) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're saying in Android platform due to `Android` tag.

Coroutines job is managed by `CoroutineDispatcher` which is determined by `CoroutineScope`, if coroutineScope don't provide `CoroutineDispatcher` than coroutine will use `Dispatchers.Default`.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html

If you're using something like `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope` they have `Dispatchers.Main` as CoroutineDispatcher ( managed by mainLooper).
If you're using something like `rememberCoroutineScope()`, `LaunchedEffect`, `produceState` in Jetpack Compose. They use `Recomposer`'s coroutineContext which provide `AndroidUiDispatcher` by default. (also managed by mainLooper)

Answer (score 0):

Flow will work in context in which collect is calling . so here we can say if you are collecting it on main then flow will work on main context . If you want to change dispatcher for emit only then you can go with `flowOn` operator which will change flow thread only .. collecting will work on different thread

Here is example and example in offical documentation

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#flowon-operator